# Workaround to retreive E-Mails using Uipath

Tags: c#, uipath

Uipath studio: 2021.10.3
Package Uipath.Mail.Activities: 1.3.0

Hi everyone,

My objective is to retrieve E-Mails from a particular E-Mail Address throught Uipath activities.

I use currently the activity "GetExchangeMailMessages" to retrieve the Emails and it works well. However, I got the following error over a period of time:

*The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive*

Forgive me if I say something incorrectly, but my understandig is the exchange protocol was not available at that time. That is why I decided to find a Workaround when it happens again. The workarround was to used the procotocol IMAP.

Uipath has the activity "GetIMAPMailMessages" in order to retrieve E-Mails. I configured this activity with following settings:

- Port: 993
- Server: The same server that I used for the exchange
  protocol
- SecureConnection: Auto

I am getting the following error:

*The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure*

I do not have enough experience working with those protocols and I do not know how to have a valid certificate.

My question is: is the IMAP workarround an option for my first error?. If so, how could I solve the final error with the IMAP activity?.

Tks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix the certificate error as the certificate is remote (i.e. belongs to the remote server you are trying to connect to).

What I would suggest is that instead of replacing your working Exchange activity, you place it inside a [try/catch block](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/try-catch).  This will allow you to catch the exception thrown in the event it happens and handle it appropriately (which could of course include attempting to retrieve the mail messages through a different route, or waiting a short time and retrying the action)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend working with the Outlook Mail Message activities instead. My experience is that they are easier to set up and also have fewer errors. However there is a dependency in form of Outlook being installed on the server/machine running the automation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).